# C# visual studio code extension will not install

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am attempting to install the C# visual studio code extension but it has been listed as "installing" for about 30 minutes now.  I tried to install via the command line as well and received the following error:
`Installing extensions... self signed certificate in certificate chain`.  Other extensions outside of C# are installing with no issues.  Does anyone have any suggestions as to check why the installation is taking so long or what the issue may be?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thats corporate firewall self signed cert. issue.

- Install win-ca extension
- File>Preferences>Settings>win-ca> select inject method: append
- restart vscode
  Worked for me.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  Unfortunately did not work for me :/